# Overbar as counter in a loop

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to create a table with four different counters that I want to call $a, \bar{a}, b, \bar{b}$. For that my obvious code is

$$\text{Table}\left[p\left[a,\bar{a},b,\bar{b}\right],\{a,0,1\},\left\{\bar{a},0,1\right\},\{b,0,1\},\left\{\bar{b},0,1\right\}\right] // \text{Grid}$$

which returns

```
{{p[0,0,0,0],p[0,1,0,1]},{p[0,1,1,0],p[0,1,1,1]}}   {{p[0,0,0,0],p[0,1,0,1]},{p[0,1,1,0],p[0,1,1,1]}}
{{p[1,0,0,0],p[1,0,0,1]},{p[1,0,1,0],p[1,1,1,1]}}   {{p[1,1,0,0],p[1,1,0,1]},{p[1,0,1,0],p[1,1,1,1]}}
```

However a quick look shows that this is not the expected result - elements in the first row are repeated. If I write

```
Table[p[a, c, b, d] , {a, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {d, 0, 1}] // Grid
```

instead then I get the desired output. So my question is double:

1. Why does it happen?
2. How can it be fixed? That is, can I use variables such as $\bar{a}$ or $a'$ or $a_1$ for loops modifying something or I am forced to used other names which do not involve these symbols?

Comment: There is `ABar` character. Enter it as `esc a- esc` not sure about `BBar` though. It works for ABar

Comment: I am introducing the overbar as `a ctrl+& _`. Isn't it the same then? At any rate `esc b- esc` produces nothing.

Comment: If you don't have use bbar then use ebar as `esc e- esc`

Comment: In order to see all special character go to `Palettes->Basic Math Assis->Second option at Type Setting->All Special Symbols and Character`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could give [`OverBar`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OverBar) the [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst) attribute so that it doesn't depend on the value of a:

```
SetAttributes[OverBar,HoldFirst]
```

Then:

```
t1 = Table[
    p[a, OverBar[a], b, OverBar[b]],
    {a, 0, 1}, {OverBar[a], 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {OverBar[b], 0, 1}
];
t2 = Table[p[a, c, b, d], {a, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {d, 0, 1}];

t1 === t2
```

> True

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that Mathematica treats `OverBar` as a function, so `OverBar[a]` is a function of your symbol `a`, not an independent symbol.

I would avoid using such symbols, but if the appearance is important to you, investigate the `Symbolize` functionality of the `Notation` package.